# with python-docx is there a way to set the Theme that is used for the document

Tags: python-docx

When I create a new document it starts with the them "Basic (Simple)" is there a way to specify the them like "Black & White (Classic)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Word to create an empty document using the theme you want (along with any other customizations like specific styles and so forth) and use that as the starting point when you open a document with `python-docx`:

```
document = Document("my-black-and-white-template.docx")
```

All `python-docx` is doing when you don't specify a document to open is using an internal default document, which is the Basic (Simple) theme you mention; it is whatever was the default style for a new document in a fresh Word installation at the time that part of the `python-docx` library was written. It's that way for convenience in getting started and when you don't really care too much about the theme.

Comment: So it uses the initial document as a template, and doesn't modify that document? That makes sense from the user documentation that it starts from that document and modifies it and saving, so sort of a save as. Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's quite right. Although it can appear otherwise, `python-docx` can only _edit_ a Word document. Either you give it one to edit, like a template, or you let it use its built-in default document. The action of the `.save()` method is a lot like SaveAs in the Word menu, as you observe, except that `python-docx` doesn't keep track of the document you opened when you started (so there's no operation like Save) and it would be unusual and probably not recommended to ever overwrite the file you started with because you could not repeat the process to fix any errors then.